# Swagger, Kotlin, Spring Boot and javadoc

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger-ui

I have a project with Spring  Boot + Kotlin, and I want use Swagger to make the documentation.

The problem, I don't want repeat the document usen Javadoc and Swagger Annotations.

I show "enunciate" that use javadoc to generate data for swagger, but it does not work with Kotlin, only with java.

Using dokka I can genarate javadoc json data, but I don't know how use it for swagger.

Any ideas?